# KivyMD specific button style

Tags: button, kivymd

I am trying to learn KivyMD and I really need the Button number 7 design that is shown in the documentation here: https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.1/components/button/index.html The example code for this Button Style is just not there. It would be great if somebody can help me, thanks! [Button design 7 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7xJD.png)